# How to skip errors ng build

Tags: angular

is it possible to skip errors when I want to compile the code using ng build? I have a bug that does not want me to compile the application, but it's not a bug, just the compiler sees it as an error because it does not know exactly what it is

```
if (dataEmail.length < 1)
```

In the production version everything works for me

Comment: which error exactly do you get? Just make sure the variable has the correct type

Answer (score 0):

Use it like following and error will be removed.

```
if (dataEmail?.length < 1)
```

OR

```
if (dataEmail && (dataEmail.length < 1))
```